# Supervisord - How to use command with space in file path

Tags: macos, supervisord

Using supervisord, I am unable to use a file path with a space in one of the directories. I am trying to use my iCloud Drive folder as the path to the file.

the path:

```
~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Code/modbot/modbot.py
```

my program supervisord.conf (non working. works when pointed to a new path without a space in the directory)

```
[program:modbot]
command=/Users/Jonathan/.virtualenvs/modbot/bin/python3.7 /Users/Jonathan/code/modbot/modbot.py
```

paths I've tired in supervisord.conf:

```
~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Code/modbot/modbot.py
~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Code/modbot/modbot.py
~/Library/Mobile' 'Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Code/modbot/modbot.py
"~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Code/modbot/modbot.py"
~/Library/"Mobile Documents"/com~apple~CloudDocs/Code/modbot/modbot.py
```

After googling I even tried double escaping but nothing is working.

Answer (score 1):

turns out I'm an idiot. supervisord doesn't use ~ so that was the problem, working code:

```
[program:modbot]
command=/Users/Jonathan/.virtualenvs/modbot/bin/python3.7 "/Users/Jonathan/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Code/modbot/modbot.py"
```